# Angular.js - adding colors/classes on items added to to-do list

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm having trouble adding a class to a form I have on my site. Basically what I'm trying to do is make an event list, where you input an event name, select from four options that categorize the event into categories 1, 2, 3 or 4. Depending on which category you select and click "Add Event", it should add a class to the text that is inputted and post it below in a list format, with that color added to the text. I cannot figure out how to add a class to what is added to the list. I'm pretty new to angular so any help would be appreciated.

```
var app = angular.module('eventApp', []); 
app.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.todoList = [{todoText:'Football Game', done:false}];

$scope.todoAdd = function() {
    $scope.todoList.push({todoText:$scope.todoInput, done:false});
    $scope.todoInput = "";
};

$scope.remove = function() {
    var oldList = $scope.todoList;
    $scope.todoList = [];
    angular.forEach(oldList, function(x) {
        if (!x.done) $scope.todoList.push(x);
    });
};
});
```

I have a form here in my html:

```
<form ng-submit="todoAdd()">
Event Name: <input type="text" ng-model="todoInput"><br><br>
Event Category: <select class="category" name="eventtype">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>

</select><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Add to Calendar">
```

and my class divs in css:

```
<style>
body {padding: 10px;}
.red {color: red;}
.blue {color: blue;}
.green {color: green;}
.yellow {color: yellow;}
</style>
```

Thanks for the help

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xssz7vfn/2/)

Comment: Can u make a demo in jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: added it to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to create like following.

[Plnkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mAVdM8zSpoMFfBgMSLPe?p=preview)

Add one more field called ***todoClass*** in the object and add it in the array.
Add that todoClass as class using ng-class when you do *ng-repeat*

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


    <form ng-submit="todoAdd()">
    Event Name: <input type="text" ng-model="event.todoInput"><br><br>
    Event Category: <select class="category" name="todoClass" ng-model="event.todoClass" ng-init="event.todoClass='red'">
        <option value="red">1</option>
        <option value="blue">2</option>
        <option value="green">3</option>
        <option value="yellow">4</option>

    </select><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add to Calendar">
</form>
    <hr>
    <h4>TODO</h4>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList" >
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" />
        <span ng-class="todo.todoClass" ng-bind="todo.todoText"></span>

      </li>

    </ul>
    <button ng-click="removeTodo()">Remove Selected</button>

  </body>
```

**Controller JS**

```
$scope.event={};

  $scope.todoList = [{todoText:'Football Game', done:false, todoClass:'red'}];

  $scope.todoAdd = function() {
    $scope.todoList.push({todoText:$scope.event.todoInput, done:false,todoClass:$scope.event.todoClass});
    $scope.event.todoInput = "";
    $scope.event.todoClass="red";
  };

    $scope.removeTodo = function() {
        var oldList = $scope.todoList;
        $scope.todoList = [];
        angular.forEach(oldList, function(x) {
            if (!x.done) $scope.todoList.push(x);
        });
    };
```

Note that instead of values 1,2,3 and 4 I added red, blue, green and yellow as value in all options. and that is added to JSON object